# TypeError: destroy() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, pygame

That is the error that I get when I try to remove a sprite from it's list so that it is erased from the screen. I am able to bring up that sprite by pressing a key but this happens when I try to remove it.
I was kind of winging my own code with the help of Purpongie's [collision detection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5ukY1GbnZU&index=18&list=PLDV1Zeh2NRsB1l23YFY137LtPcstXKyuQ) video.

For now I will show you mine with most unrelated things omitted:

Main.py

```
while True:
    process(Select)
    H2Ps.destroy()
    H2Ps.List.draw(screen)
```

Classes.py

```
class BaseClass(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
allsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
def __init__(self, x, y, image_string):

    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    BaseClass.allsprites.add(self)

    self.image = pygame.image.load(image_string)

    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = x
    self.rect.y = y


def destroy(self, ClassName):
    ClassName.List.remove(self)
    BaseClass.allsprites.remove(self)
    del self



class H2Ps(BaseClass):
List = pygame.sprite.Group()

def __init__ (self,x,y,image_string):
    BaseClass.__init__(self,x,y,image_string)
    H2Ps.List.add(self)

@staticmethod
def destroy():
    for test in H2Ps.List:
        if (pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_ESCAPE]):
            test.destroy(H2Ps)
```

Process.py

```
def process(Select):
    if Select.rect.collidepoint(370,400): #How to play
        if keys[pygame.K_RETURN]:
            HowToPlay = H2Ps(0,0,"Images/How To Play.png")
```

I believe that the error is pointing out that there is something wrong with `test.destroy(H2Ps)` in Classes.py. I have run it earlier and it seemed to have worked but now I am unsure of what I may have changed that would break it. I would greatly appreciate some solutions.

Comment: You have two destroy() functions in Classes.py, one takes a parameter and the other doesn't. I'm not actually sure what Python's behaviour is in this instance.

Comment: His indentation is off; both are methods of distinct classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overridden `destroy(self, ClassName)` in `BaseClass` with your `destroy()` static method in `H2Ps`.  You need to change the name of one of them!

So, when you call `H2Ps.destroy()` in main.py, you are calling your static method, this then loops through `List`:

```
for test in H2Ps.List:
    if (pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_ESCAPE]):
        test.destroy(H2Ps)
```

`test` here is an `H2Ps` object, and when you do `test.destroy(H2Ps)`, so are *still* calling the static method defined on `H2Ps`, not the method `destroy(self, ClassName)` on `BaseClass`.

Unlike in some other languages, methods can be differentiated by their arguments, so in Java for example, the compiler can tell the difference between these methods:

```
public void destroy(String className);
public static void destroy();
```

Python doesn't work like that, and chooses which method to call by name only.  When you override `destroy` in `H2Ps` you are replacing the definition of `destroy(self, ClassName)` with `destroy()`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what I need to do. Could you explain what I'd need to change? And a little bit of why?

Comment: I added some extra details, hope that helps.